# Проблема с обновлением скрипта и стилей

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, cookie, update

Есть [сайт](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/forum/) в системе **ucoz** 
на сайте есть скрипты и стиль, который лежать в корен сайте, как и у всех.
если я в скрипте или стиле обновляю  какой то функции, при загрузке в корен сайта,
страница берет не ту который я обновил, берет который было до обновление, для примера удалял тот скрипт в корен сайте, который не обновляется, в таком случай я не должен видеть тот скрипт который удалял, все равно она появляется при просмотре код того страницу, это случается не всегда, пробовал обновит страницу, пробовал перезагрузит компьютер, опят так же. не знаю это почему так, если сервер ucoz глючит, тогда почему после удаление опят вижу тот который удали, я так думаю что это записывается в куки, и берется оттуда, выходит такой вопрос, почему не всегда ?

Если вы зайдете на это сайт посмотрите с верху рядом поиска с права, должен быт **dropdown** меню с флагом и имя страны, в этом меню ранее было дизайн  button как в **botstrap menu** я это дизайн поменял как мне нужно, загрузил в корен сайта, дизайн остался как и есть, может быт у вас покажется обновленная версия, но у меня почему то нет,

Answer (score 1):

Возможно закешировано все, попробуйте после изменений в файле сбросить кеш с помощью ctrl+f5, если не поможет то перепроверте через настройки браузера скиньте, если и это не поможет - скорее всего вы правите не те файлы...лучше приложите ссылку на сайт...

Comment: ссылка на сайт вставил посмотрите в теме

Comment: Спасибо ctrl+f5 помогло, такой вопрос почему это кеширование как это происходит?

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста как вы зайдете на это [сайт](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/forum/) рядом поиска с верху какой флаг и какой надпись уведите,

Comment: Если помогло то укажите ответ верным, кеширование может быть настроено по разному...это может и htacces - правила, а может и сам хостинг...тут надо смотреть...

Comment: флаг украина на сайте отображается

Comment: мне нет доступа в htacces мой сайт на бесплатно хостинге ucoz,  скорое всего это хостинг глючит

Comment: Это в принципе не глюк...кеширование это удобная и полезная тема

Comment: спасибо вам за ответь, флаг Украины это хорошо а вы сейчас  в Украине? и еще рядом флаг Украины должен быт надпись по Украинском, тоже есть ?

Comment: Да, все верно, отметите ответ правильным?)